# Geocoding for the emergency services

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding, bing-maps, reverse-geocoding

I'm currently developing an application for the emergency services (target market is NY) A crucial part of the application is the mapping feature. I'm currently using Google maps API and Bing, as a proof of concept, and it's working great. I like google a lot better as it seems to have more features and looks better. I've been finding that sometimes google is inaccurate about 10-20% of the time (Bing is also inaccurate, but not as much). It's working for a proof of concept, but as this is for emergency services, I need the maps to be as accurate as possible. I wouldn't have a problem using one API to geocode, and then use google to display. Does anyone know a good geocoding service out there that could live up to these standards? (Free would be best, but I'd take fee based services suggestions too)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this you really want to pay someone and get support, corrections, fixes etc on demand.   Mapquest might have an offering that suits you (and their geocoding is generally very good).

Comment: I'm leaning towards Navteq as it looks to be the better looking map and the most accurate. I've been trying to find a price for it because my use for it doesn't fall within their terms of service. Google is too inaccurate, and Microsoft the maps aren't as nice as I would like.